# How to write code to summarise means from two character variables for comparative graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just getting into using R and working on a data set that looks at the median age of women getting married in each state in 2006-2010 and 2015-2019.

I have the below plot using the following code:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=TimeFrame, y=Median.Age, group=1)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

However, instead of having an individual dot for each state, I would like to summarise the mean age for marriage in 2006-2010 and 2015-2019 among all states in order to have two comparative means and compare them like that.

How can I go about this?

Comment: See `?stat_summary` and [the example](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary.html). Something like `ggplot(df, aes(TimeFrame, Median.Age, group = 1)) + stat_summary(fun = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "pointrange") + stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line")`

Comment: By the way, do you know of a way that I could change the size of the mean dot? I have tried to put size=2 in the stat_summary() to no avail

Comment: Play around with `size` and `fatten`.